# Voodoo Bakka or Specialized Hotrock (kids mountain bike)

Tags: specialized-bikes

New bike for my son, (8). Torn between Voodd Bakka moutnin bike 24'' or Specialized Hotrock 24'' (both 2020) both similar price at £320. towpaths, parks, woods and odd trial. Kent based.

Open to other ideas if you know any better for same price point?

Comment: Sorry Tom, we normally don't bother with these types of questions, because they can be subjective and go out of date quickly. What might matter right now is which one you can find in stock!

Comment: Thanks Swifty, got you.

Comment: Take your son to the shop and try them both out.  Expect him to choose the red one.